# Multi parent for a state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I actually work on angularJS and I have a problem with state from angular-UI so I have a state A and B which has the same templeteUrl and I have a state C which has two state D and E as son and I would like to know if it is possible to have A and B as parent of C? 
Thank,

Answer (score -1):

If your question is whether a state can have multiple parents, there is an already closed question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386009/angular-ui-router-child-state-with-multiple-parent-states).

To sum up:

> This kind of hierarchy would go against the DOM tree structure, which by definition doesn't allow multiple parents of same element.

For that kind of need, the directive it's usually the better solution.

Comment: Ops, ok, I will know from now on. I have corrected the answer, hope it's okey now